# Windows ODBC performance

Tags: c, excel, database, performance, odbc

We am importing/fetching data from a Server into Microsoft Excel via ODBC connection.
For a data set with 5 columns and 10000 rows it is roughly taking 10mins to pull data.
The time to import/fetch data to excel increases when the columns increase.We can confirm that the Network connection is fast and is not the cause for slowness.

Is there any way we can decrease the time taken to fetch ? Increase performance of import/fetch ? Any best-practices or tuning which needs to be done. ?
We are using excel 32 bit v16 and windows 10.

Comment: 10 minutes is an eternity. Could you isolate on which side that time is spent? Like just fetch the data and do nothing with it? Does your sheet have any formulas depending on the imported data? You could also try to lock screen updates for the duration of that import.

Comment: We don't have any formulas on the sheet .it is just a simple load from ODBC Driver.     What we found out is, that the slowness is result of directly calling SQLFetch() every row and then SQLGetData() for every column. That is the reason when the columns are higher in the result-set the time take also increases. What we were expecting is that SQLBindCol() should be called to make the pull faster. Net-Net, Maximum time is spend in SQLGetData() which is called for each and every column in a row.

Comment: Is there any way to configure Excel to call SQLBindCol() instead of SQLFetch().